# EDM for campaign monitor - padding everywhere

Tags: html, campaign-monitor, cellpadding

Sorry if this is a silly question - I've searched everywhere and I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem.

Basically I'm creating an EDM and even though I have spacing and padding down as 0 in all of my table tags (that contain info) there still seems to be padding within it.

Some table tags do have cell spacing but that's only for the tables acting as breakers between other tables. EDM's are a little bit of a bi@tch to get consistent across all email clients so you might see a few funny things going on within my code.

Hopefully you guys can spot something I'm missing.

Thanks for your help :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>S2 Monthly Newsletter</title>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
a:visited { color: #ff9201 !important; }
a:hover { color: #ff9201 !important; }
a:active { color: #ff9201 !important; }
></style>

<!-- 100% table -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr>
<td>
<!-- Wrapper table -->
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center"><tr>
<td>

<!-- StepTwo Academy Images -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"><tr>
<td width="261" align="left"><img editable src="coins_hand_206729392-260.175905.jpg" width="260"></td>
                <td width="78" align="left"></td>
                <td width="261" align="left"><img editable src="coins_hand_206729392-260.175905.jpg" width="260"></td>
              </tr></table>

<!-- StepTwo Academy Headings -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"><tr>
<td width="261" align="left"><h3 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #505050;">
                    
                    <singleline label="Title">Title</singleline>
</h3></td>

                <td width="78" align="left"></td>
                
                <td width="261" align="left"><h3 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #505050;">
                    <singleline label="Title">Title</singleline>
</h3></td>
              </tr></table>

<!-- StepTwo Academy Body text-->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left"><tr>
<td width="261" align="left" valign="top"><p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; font-size: 16px; color: #505050;">
                    <multiline label="spiel">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consaonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</multiline></p></td>
                    
                <td width="78" align="left"></td>
                
                <td width="261" align="left" valign="top"><p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 1.8em; font-size: 16px; color: #505050;">
                    <multiline label="spiel">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consaonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</multiline></p></td>
              </tr></table>



<!-- End of wrapper table below -->
</td>
        </tr></table>
<!-- End of 100% table -->
</td>
  </tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a LOT of code. Have you narrowed down at all where the error might be occurring? I'd recommend [paring this down to as little code as possible while still reproducing the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: True, sorry - I'm at the end of my rope so I'm just blasting this all at once.
I'll do that now and update the post.

Cheers

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what is an EDM? It is a pretty vague acronym https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDM

Comment: EDM = Electronic Distributed Mail which is a HTML stylised email. In my experience a lot of businesses refer to them as EDM's but maybe it's an Aussie thing? Not sure

Comment: @AndrewLaPrise I've cut the code down and it's still reproducing the problem - wish I could include a snapshot. I'm thinking it might be the TD tags that make up the middle column? I haven't specified a height because I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible so Gmail and Outlook don't freak out but I've given it a try and it still doesn't make a difference - in chrome or in the test email I send.

Comment: :( this is so crazy - I still can't figure out what's wrong.